# Inno Setup - Save a string to a very specific location in a file

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I need the user to edit a custom file format. The format is as follows:

```
Line 1:   3 2290 //3 columns, 2290 lines, not processed
Line 2:   "Index" "Primary" "Secondary" //Column names, not processed
Lines 3+: "Name" "Primary Action" "Secondary Action" // Processed
```

Here's my code showing how I load lines, and trim them to cells:

```
var
  Col2,Col3: AnsiString;
// At this point column 1 is already loaded into a ListBox
Procedure LoadColumns(Sender: TObject);
var
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  Line: AnsiString;
  P: Integer;
begin  
  LoadStringsFromFile(FileName, Lines);
  Line := Lines[IndexList.ItemIndex + 2]; //Skip first 2 lines
  P := Pos('" "', Line);
  Delete(Line, 1, P + 1);
  P := Pos('" "', Line);
  Col2 := RemoveQuotes(Copy(Line, 1, P)); //Loaded Column2 of the line to _global_ variable Col2
  Delete(Line, 1, P + 1);
  Col3 := RemoveQuotes(Copy(Line, 1, Length(Line))); //Loaded Column3 of the line to _global_ variable Col3
  Primary.Text := ConvertToCR(Col2);
  Secondary.Text := ConvertToCR(Col3);
end;


Procedure SavetoPrimary(Sender: TObject);
var
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  Line: String;
  FromString, SaveString: AnsiString;
  P, ChangeResult: Integer;
begin  
  LoadStringsFromFile(FileName, Lines);
  Line := String(Lines[IndexList.ItemIndex + 2]);
  FromString := ' "' + Col2 + '" ';
  SaveString := ' "' + AnsiString(ConvertFromCR(Primary.Text)) + '" ';
  ChangeResult := StringChangeEx(Line,FromString,SaveString,True)
  if ChangeResult <> 1 then
  begin
    MsgBox('Your code sucks!', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
  end
  else
  begin
    MsgBox('OK, that works.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

Procedure SavetoSecondary(Sender: TObject);
var
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  Line: String;
  SaveString: AnsiString;
  P, ChangeResult: Integer;
begin  
  LoadStringsFromFile(FileName, Lines);
  Line := String(Lines[IndexList.ItemIndex + 2]);
  SaveString := AnsiString(ConvertFromCR(Secondary.Text));
  ChangeResult := StringChangeEx(Line,Col3,SaveString,True)
  if ChangeResult <> 1 then
  begin
    MsgBox('Your code sucks!', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
  end
  else
  begin
    MsgBox('OK, that works.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

The `SaveToPrimary` is different, because `Index` and `Primary` may actually be the very same string.

As you can see, I never actually got to `SaveStringToFile`, since I have no idea how to tell it to save at a specific location.

Comment: This is way too localized question for SO. Please narrow down your question to a specific programming problem.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The code is provided for reference only. The main question is still the saving part. I'm deleting the carriage return part, but other than that I'm not sure what else to change.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the saving part.

Comment: Is your file really containing `\n` i.e. backslash and n? Because that's what your code looks for. It does not "delete carriage return", it actually replaces backslash and n with carriage  return and line feed and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, the file contains `\n`, that I'm converting to carriage return before loading to Memo. And I want to revert it back to `\n` before saving.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Do I just remove the code, so the question basically becomes "Here's a celled (delimited?) file format. How to save to a cell?" ?

Comment: No, you should try to sketch steps needed to update the file. And then you try to implement the steps. And you ask questions about the steps that you do not know how to implement.

Comment: Good. But actually now I do not understand your problem. You wrote *"I have no idea how to tell it to save at a specific location"* - What do you mean by location? Originally I've understood it as a *"location in the file"*, but you already have replaced the new contents at the correct location (at least it seems to). So what's your actual problem?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, in the file. I need to save to a cell either in column 2 (`Primary`) or 3 (`Secondary`). I've loaded the `Line`, replaced the content of the cell, now I need to save it back.

Comment: So is your question how to save `Lines: TArrayOfString` to a file? Use [`SaveStringsToFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_savestringstofile).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No, not `Lines`, `Line`. Look inside `SaveSecondary`. I've tried using `SaveStringToFile` but it just adds the line at the end. I need to specify a _location_ inside the file where to save to, and somehow tell that location to `SaveStringToFile`

Comment: OK, so put the `Line` back to `Lines`: `Lines[IndexList.ItemIndex + 2] := Line;` and then save the `Lines`. But using `SaveString**s**ToFile` not `SaveStringToFile`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, that works.... I can't believe that what I've been cracking my head on for the past 2 days was a matter of just 2 lines. Please, post it as an answer, so I can set it as one.